# Input method for android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

I am trying to create simple contact list app in android,i want to add phone keypad into my app to dial a number, and then this number will be display on to list,i have a sq-lite database, i can create contact and that will save into database i can also edit the contact, but now i want to add keypad in my front activity, i goggled it but i don't have find satisfied result from this so please help me and guide from where i should have to start.

your help would highly be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Means you want to put your own button like 1 ,2 and so on and when user press it, it should type that number inside your text field. Is this what you are looking for???

Comment: no i want to add android input method, phone keypad,or keyboard but i dont how to add this into my app,

Comment: Okay, so basically for entering number what you have used, i mean edit-text or what???

Comment: i dont have such idea, that why i put a question here

Comment: Ok, post your code till what you have done. By seeing your code only i can help further.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Action_Dial`,

use below code it will open Dialer with number specified

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1231231234"));
startActivity(intent);
```